# Настройка каскадного удаления в Entity Framework 6 (DataBase First) после внесения изменений в БД

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть таблица `purchases`, на нее ссылается таблица `goods`. Внешние ключи настроены на каскадное удаление, то есть при удалении записи из `purchases`, должны удаляться все `goods`. Это так и работает, если удалять запись вручную (не из кода, а через редактор таблиц БД). В EF я удаляю так

```
CommonData.DataContext.Purchases.Remove(curPur);
CommonData.DataContext.SaveChanges();
```

где `сurPur` - объект `Purchase`. В итоге EF отвязывает `goods` от `Purchase`, то есть ставить в NULL внешние ключи, после чего удаляет `Purchase`. 
Вот запросы от EF (он действительно делает так как я написал):

```
UPDATE [dbo].[goods]
SET [purchaseID] = NULL
WHERE ([goodID] = @0)

-- @0: '10' (Type = Int32)

-- Выполнение в 27.10.2015 11:12:25 +03:00

-- Выполнено за 1 мс. Результат: 1



UPDATE [dbo].[goods]
SET [purchaseID] = NULL
WHERE ([goodID] = @0)

-- @0: '11' (Type = Int32)

-- Выполнение в 27.10.2015 11:12:25 +03:00

-- Выполнено за 0 мс. Результат: 1



UPDATE [dbo].[goods]
SET [purchaseID] = NULL
WHERE ([goodID] = @0)

-- @0: '12' (Type = Int32)

-- Выполнение в 27.10.2015 11:12:25 +03:00

-- Выполнено за 0 мс. Результат: 1



DELETE [dbo].[purchases]
WHERE ([purchaseID] = @0)
```

Также стоит заметить, что настройка внешних ключей в БД на каскадное удаление осуществлялась после создания модели .edmx в Entity Framework. Обновление модели на основе БД проблему не устранило.
Как это исправить?

Comment: не совсем понял что подразумевается под не *ручным* удалением, и что хочется исправить?

Comment: @Bald56rus Ручное - это из базы (я через визуальный редактор делаю) строку выделил - удалить - все удалилось. Не ручное - это из кода приложения, как и показал. Нужно чтобы все удалялось связанное, а не отвязывалось.

Comment: т.е. у Вас остаются записи в таблице goods?

Comment: а нет ли у вас случайно такой строчки в контексте? `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();`

Comment: @Dmitry Нет наверно.  где ее найти или куда вставить?

Comment: в контексте работы с базой есть метод `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)`, но эта строчка на самом деле говорит о том, что удалять каскадно не нужно

Comment: @Dmitry Нет, у меня там просто `throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();` стоит и все

Comment: можете посмотреть контекстное меню для связи с генерированной конструктором EF для Вашей  бд, есть предположение что там надо где то включить каскадное удаление

Comment: А вы случайно модель генерировали не до того как добавили каскадное удаление в базу? В любом случае имеет смысл снести и пересоздать маппинг для чистоты эксперимента и посмотреть прописывается ли каскадное удаление в модели.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin да после. Однако все удалять пересоздавать заново это как то нехорошо - я несколько раз обновлял модель, то есть правой кнопкой по диаграмме - обновить модель на основе базы - обновить. И вообще это где-то в свойствах модели посмотреть можно?

Comment: "Обновить модель", оно "плохо" работает (уж не знаю почему, возможно оно просто не для этого сделано). Пересоздать всегда лучше. Да можно посмотреть в файле edmx поищите строку `OnDelete Action="Cascade"` там по контексту должно быть понятно к чему это относится, если её нет значит в модели не "прописалось".

Comment: @PetrAbdulin спасибо, ваши комментарии помогли мне найти решение.

Comment: @RussCoder пожалуйста, рад что помогло :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как правильно заметил @PetrAbdulin, я перенастроил внешние ключи на каскадное удаление уже после создания модели .edmx. Несмотря на то, что я ее несколько раз обновлял на основе БД, ничего не менялось (точнее менялось, но не все). Вот тут [Microsoft пишет в заметке](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716697(v=vs.100).aspx):

> The conceptual model will be updated only for objects that are added to the database. All other changes to the conceptual model must be made manually. For information about updating the conceptual model, see [Entity Data Model Tools Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738480(v=vs.100).aspx)
>
> Концептуальная модель будет обновляться только для объектов, которые добавлены в базу. Все остальные изменения концептуальной модели должны быть сделаны вручную. Информация об обновлении концептуальной модели доступна по ссылке [Entity Data Model Tools Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738480(v=vs.100).aspx)

Интересен тот факт (который может ввести в заблуждение), что в .edmx (если его открыть как .xml файл) в разделе `<edmx:StorageModels>` все изменяется:

```
<Association Name="R_5">
   <End Role="purchases" Type="Self.purchases" Multiplicity="0..1">
     <OnDelete Action="Cascade" /> <!-- Вот нужное место -->
   </End>
   <End Role="goods" Type="Self.goods" Multiplicity="*" />
   <ReferentialConstraint>
     <Principal Role="purchases">
       <PropertyRef Name="purchaseID" />
     </Principal>
     <Dependent Role="goods">
       <PropertyRef Name="purchaseID" />
     </Dependent>
   </ReferentialConstraint>
 </Association>
```

А вот в разделе  `<edmx:ConceptualModels>` это не происходит, то есть

```
<Association Name="R_5">
  <End Role="purchases" Type="JPModel.Purchase" Multiplicity="0..1" /> <!-- Ничего не изменилось -->
  <End Role="goods" Type="JPModel.Good" Multiplicity="*" />
  <ReferentialConstraint>
    <Principal Role="purchases">
      <PropertyRef Name="purchaseID" />
    </Principal>
    <Dependent Role="goods">
      <PropertyRef Name="purchaseID" />
    </Dependent>
  </ReferentialConstraint>
</Association>
```

Если пересоздать все заново (кстати для экспериметов лучше создать пустой проект с несколькими строками кода, а не переделывать модель в текущем проекте), то все заработает как надо. Однако есть более легкий путь (можно еще .xml поправить, наверное, но не пробовал).

На диаграмме классов выбирает нужную связь и в свойствах меняем  OnDelete на Cascade

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И это нужно поделать со всеми связями в проекте, для которых настроено каскадное удаление.

Answer (score -2):

Добавить в метод

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
    modelBuilder.Entity<Purchases>()
       .HasMany<Good>(a => a.Goods)
       .WithRequired(a => a.Purchase)
       .HasForeignKey(a => a.PurchaseID)
       .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

Для DB First удаление можно реализовать через репозиторий:

```
public static void Remove(Purchase model)
{
   using (var сontextTransact = context.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
   {
      try
      {
         model.Goods.RemoveRange(model.Goods.ToArray());
         context.Purchases.Remove(model);
         context.SaveChanges();
         сontextTransact.Commit();
       }
       catch(Exception)
       {
          сontextTransact.Rollback(); 
       }
   }
}
```

Тогда вам из кода не надо будет заниматься удалением связанных объектов, за вас это сделает репозиторий.

P.S. Писал по памяти, возможны ошибки

Comment: `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);` разве здесь не должно быть `true`?

Comment: `OnModelCreating` не используется в Db First подходе, т.к. конфигурация базы описана в EDMX модели. Собственно там эксепшен заглушка для этого и вставлена - этот метод не должен вызыватся и не вызывается при Db First.

Comment: @Bald56rusБ действительно, ошибся :)

Comment: ну по хорошему тогда это надо делать еще и внутри транзакции что бы удалить либо все либо ничего :)

Comment: @Bald56rus согласен